# Understanding OnPaint method

Tags: c#, winforms, label, smoothing

I'm working on some project witch has a lot of labels. I have a task to make labels smoother because it looks ugly. I wrote my custom `LabelEx` class which extends `Label` class. Then I overrided `OnPaint()` method like this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(e);
   e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
}
```

But it does not work. I still have my old ugly labels.

Help me understand the meaning of `OnPaint` method. How does it work? I want my labels to have the properties which I set to them in `myClass.cs[Design]` (Location, Size, TextAlign, Font). I just need to make them smoother.

[image: This is what I call "ugly"]

Comment: It would help to be able to see what "ugly" means to you.  A screenshot?

Comment: Updated. I need the letters to be more smooth.

Comment: How about [SmoothingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Are you sure setting the `Graphics.TextRenderingHint` should be below the drawing itself (in the `base.OnPaint(e);`)?

Comment: @Dmitry I tried both ways, none works.

Comment: Your existing text already uses ClearType anti-aliasing, as expected, that's as good as it is going to get on an LCD monitor.  Using TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias produces a lesser quality that uses greyscale anti-aliasing.  The proper choice only for non-monitor output such as a bitmap or a printer.  You probably either need to use the ClearType tuner or a higher resolution monitor to get a better result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Label OnPaint use GDI (System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer), and not GDI+ (System.Drawing.Graphics), to use GDI+ you need to set UseCompatibleTextRendering True and change your GDI+ Options BEFORE call base.OnPaint(e);
Here's a example:

```
public class LabelEx : System.Windows.Forms.Label
{
    public LabelEx()
    {
        UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        // You can try this two options too.
        //e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        //e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know when I test this.

Comment: You're welcome. If you need more customization let me know, i can show you how to replace base.OnPaint

Comment: It worked with TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias. All I had to change was to write base.OnPaint(e) above Antialias and set UseCompatibleTextRendering = true; Thank you very much.